# A/C Sealant Risks?

Tags: ac, repair

I've got an 11 year old vehicle that recently developed a small pin-sized hole in the condenser coil (e.g. the shop put in some dye to identify the source of the leak).  I've found that adding sealant within my home unit has done a great job of extending the life of my central air condenser, so I asked about taking a similar approach here.  The shop was pretty adamant that putting sealant into the system wasn't something they would consider doing, so I called a few other places to see if any were willing.  The general consensus I got was that no shop puts sealant in with some going so far as to say they wouldn't work on a car if sealant *had* been put into the system at any point prior.

I assume the disdain for A/C sealant has to do with shops not wanting it to gum up a recovery machine, but are there any other issues with A/C sealant that I'm not aware of?  Is it also safe to say that if I want to put sealant into my vehicle's A/C system, it's going to be a do-it-yourself job?  I'm fine doing it myself, but having heard a similar response from a number of different auto shops has me a bit concerned I'm missing something here.

Comment: Where is the pin size leak on the condenser? On the fin. Or sides of condenser.  Is the condenser metal, plastic and metal?

Comment: @cano The shop just told me "the coil" so I would suspect it's on a fin.  The condenser is metal (aluminum).

Comment: Well, I've seen people actually pinch off the fin at the leak area. On vehicles they did not want to put money into. Have you priced a condenser? I think they're pretty low on coat now. I've personally have never used the sealant in the system.

Comment: "I assume the disdain for A/C sealant has to do with shops not wanting it to gum up a recovery machine" Correct. I have been a tech in the auto industry for 40 years, never used it either and will not work on any system I suspect has has sealer installed, as it can damage very expensive equipment I use.